# Echo executes but internal server error?

Tags: php

This out puts but has 500 error

```
class Article
{
    public function fetch_all()
    {
        echo "test";
    }
}

$article = new Article();
$data = $article->fetch_all();

echo $data;
```

This will echo output with an internal server error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
class Article
{

    public function fetch_all()
    {
       return "test";
    }

}

$article = new Article();
$data = $article->fetch_all(); // a-     >b will cause a syntax error
echo $data;
```

Comment: Sorry i posted code from phone. No white spacers on comp, will return fix the problem?

Comment: yepp, it will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know but just clear up that whitespace on the method, and use `return`.

```
class Article
{
    public function fetch_all()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}

$article = new Article();
$data = $article->fetch_all();

echo $data;
```